How can I support butcherblock shelves without seeing brackets
I'm trying to install floating shelves made of 3/4 in butcherblock to match the countertops. The client would like the mounting hardware to be invisible if possible but these shelves will have substantial weight without anything on them. Is there any other way to do it besides drilling into hollow out a hole and hiding the bracket inside?

It's not just how the bracket attaches to the shelf... way more important is how the bracket attaches to the wall. What are the dimensions of the shelf? What is the anticipated load of the shelf in use?

try this https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CS61VKCW/ref=sspa_dk_hqp_detail_aax_0?sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9ocXBfc2hhcmVk&th=1

So you are a "professional" doing this for a client? why not use 1/2" rebar as spikes?

@SolarMike ar should be stiff enough, how do you suggest fixing it into the wall? Here I could drill deep into the masonry and fix it in with adhesive or even mortar, with temporary support to make sure it's actually level (the plasterboard drylining would make all of that harder). Could you just insert rebar into the studs?

@ChrisH I used 3 rebar "pins" 8" long to support an oak beam (5' long by 6" deep and 5" wide), with 3" in the beam and 5" in the wall. Luckily the wall was brick but the OP does not say... Hopefully The Op can recognise different wall types.

@SolarMike brick is good

Holding the shelves is easy.  Holding heavy weight on the shelves is where it gets interesting.  Shelf brackets that can have a dual propose of holding nick-knacks/small plants/herbs might be better than a hidden/floating bracket.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a DIYer problem but someone working for someone else.

You will not be able to do it with 3/4" material. it needs to be ideally 1 1/2" thick,to drill accurately 1/2" lags, 8" long, with the heads cut off, drilled dead square into the shelf and wall.

Floating shelves need to be thick, for structural reasons. If it's "matching the countertops" the visible edges of those are typically 1-1/2" thick, or more, so match that. A naked 3/4" countertop edge is highly unusual, if you actually have that.

@Ecnerwal yes, metric here but mine are about 1.5" and the thinnest I've worked with is about 1 1/8". Budget beech block stuff from IKEA, that I've got in my van and as a workbench. Anything less is very unusual

how thick is the wall? instead of trying to mount a shelf to the wall, what if you could insert the shelf into a slot in the wall; assume the exposed shelf is 3' x 8" ... cut the actual shelf to 3' x 14" (16"?), build a 'slot' in the wall in which to slide the shelf, lock/screw the shelf into the 'slot' (could be done with hardware 'in the wall'), patch the wall to cover the outline of the 'slot', you're left with what looks like a 3' x 8" shelf; shelf material would need to be strong enough to hold expected weight without sagging over time + 'slot' strong enough to not buckle from weight

I know that the industry casually redefines terms regularly, but good god, calling 3/4" material butcherblock? Regardless of construction/lamination I can't imagine referring to something thinner than 1.5" with that term.

OP - is the client your better-half and you're just being polite?   :)

The issue here is the shelves are only 3/4 inch thick.  Any hidden bracket anchored in any way may hold the weight, however The resulting thickness of the shelf will be too thin to support much weight. .75"- .5"= .25" OR even less if the support is in the middle of the shelf. .75-.5= ,25div x2= .125 or 1/8 of an inch of wood remaining.
The best answer for your question is to tell the client that their wishes cannot be safely completed and either the shelves need to be thicker or the load need to be greatly reduced, or there needs to be brackets that will be visible.

My contractor first used floating shelf brackets, drilling suitable holes in the back of the shelf. They bent. It was 10 years ago but I think the steel backplate of the bracket twisted. This is 40mm oak, so really heavy, but it would work equally well in thinner material.
Then he used brackets intended to be hidden behind the books. They were fine with the weight of the shelves, but bent when loaded (they were too flat to be stiff enough, so they'd hide better).
Finally I made these bookend brackets from offcuts. I meant to fill the holes with dowels, but decided against it.

So no longer floating, but very effective given what I use the shelves for. All the brackets used were screwed into the concrete blocks forming the inner skin of the wall, passing through plasterboard (drywall) and a small air gap on the way
